# Deploy Frontend to GitHub Pages and Backend to Heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, github-pages, npm-build, github-pages-deploy-action

I tried deploying my backend to Heroku and after I did that my website was still working on `http://localhost:3000/` but after I build the app for deployment on GitHub Pages the website stopped working on the Github page but works on the local environment.

this is my GitHub repo: https://github.com/pranjalchaplot/missedmessage/

My deployed GitHub Page (doesn't work): https://pranjalchaplot.github.io/missedmessage/

Comment: In your client folder, regenerate your static files with `npm build` and commit those files on your `gh-pages` branch.

Comment: @TinNguyen tried that but it's not working, I changed the homepage in the package.json to my GitHub pages deployed link still it's not working after building it again and committing the changes to gh-page branch

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript references are not set correctly
as seen in your html [javascript references](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gk0n7.png), when you open that in a new tab, it feeds off of the "master" url, and brings you to a [404 page](https://pranjalchaplot.github.io/static/js/2.e0b04b4c.chunk.js), you need to fix/change your reference path.

Also, the console is showing quite a few [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdPpD.png)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but can you please elaborate what to change in the script reference to and how to change the reference path?? Which index.html file I should change in? the one in the build folder or the one in the public folder? and change the location of the script to where?

Comment: your JavaScript is running back-end correct, on heroku? because the JS reference path leads to nothing, just change the reference path to the location of the JS on heroku. 

So for example `https://myapp.herokuapp.com/js/my.js`